# codeigniter form validation set_value works only for the fields which have rules

Tags: codeigniter-2

Suppose if I have two fields in my form viz first_name and last_name

I have set the validation rule only for first_name.

set_value should work for both the fields regardless of rule ? right ?

For me it works only for the fields which have rules with them !!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

set_value only works against the items you have chosen to validate using the form_validation class.

Easiest way is to pretend you are validating by adding this to your form validation config
        array(
            'field'   => 'address1',
            'label'   => '',
            'rules'   => ''
        ),

There is a hack someone has done to the CI library but I haven't been able to find the documentation on that today...Or use this modification instead:

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/159535/#775628

Comment: It's important to state that you must then also call the form_validations run method. Setting the validation rules alone is not enough.

Answer (score 3):

There is simple solution of this issue. pass `$_POST['your_field_name']` variable as a second parameter for fields those don't have any validation rule.

```
echo set_value('o_title',$_POST['o_title']);
```

It worked for me.

Comment: This isn't a good solution - it will throw an 'undefined index' error the first time you load the form as there is nothing in the $_POST array, and it doesn't allow you to provide a genuine default value if you need to.

Answer (score 3):

if you set the validation rule with just the first parameter it seems to work fine.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('city');
```

etc.

so there isn't a validation rule per se but it repopulates the field for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need set_checkbox support see this code.

[MY_form_helper.php with set_checkbox support](http://pastebin.com/h70F9esF)

Answer (score 0):

some times i use fake rule like trim or callback just to repopulate the filed data

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('city','City','trim');
```